# How to use async await in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made an api like below.
I think it works asyncrously well without doubt.

```
exports.query = async(req, res) => {
   try{
      const result = await user.findOne({})
      res.send(result);
   } catch(error) {
      res.send(error)
   }
}
```

But when I try this like below, I am not sure it works asyncrously or not.

```
exports.query = async(req, res) => {
   try{
      user.findOne({})
         .then(async(result) =>{
               order.findOne({id: result.id})
         .catch(e => res.send(e)
   } catch(error) {
      res.send(error)
   }
}
```

I have to attach 'await' in front of user.findOne({}) like below?

```
exports.query = async(req, res) => {
       try{
          await user.findOne({}) 
             .then(async(result) =>{
```

Or it doesn't matter? That is, it works same asycrously, even though I don't write await in front to user.findOne using 'then'?

thank you so much for reading.

Comment: You have to use `await` to suspend the execution of the `async` function pending on the promise returned by your chain. Your second example will not work, and additionally it contains a syntax error.

Comment: Either use `then` to chain each of the `async` functions or use `async/await` combination to run the `async` code `await user.findOne({});` and so on with a `try/catch` to handle errors. And don't mix these patterns altogether.

Comment: Patrick Roberts / thank you so much for your reply. I figured out a syntax error. And I have a question. If I don't write await even though I write async, does it works well without problem using .then of promise?

Comment: ambianBeing If i miss altogether, what happens? doesnt it work asyncrously?

Comment: If you have an `async` function but don't `await` or return a Promise, the Promise returned by the function will resolve immediately, which is usually not desirable - generally, it's best to return a Promise that resolves when the function is done with all of its work

Comment: @DDDD Understand that things like `then` and `async/await` are enablers for you to have a handle (to use the result) on async codes like the db-call `findOne`. Wether you write them or/not the code is going to run asynchronously. And hence either use one of those patterns (not both together) to for `async` codes that returns promise/es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, inside a single block, you should *either* use `await`, *or* use `.then`, but not both - similarly, using `Promise.prototype.catch` is *really weird* in combination with `try/catch` where you can already `await`.

For your `exports.query` to resolve once the second `findOne` finishes, `await` or return both Promises, *and* connect the inner `findOne` connected to the outer Promise chain. Consider something like this instead:

```
exports.query = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userResult = await user.findOne({});
    const orderResult = await userResult.findOne({ id: userResult.id });
    // do something with orderResult
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error)
  }
}
```

If you use `.then` and `catch` without `await`, then it would look like:

```
exports.query = (req, res) => {
  return user.findOne({})
    .then((result) => {
      return order.findOne({
          id: result.id
        })
        .then((orderResult) => {
          // do something with orderResult
        })
        .catch(e => res.send(e))
    });
}
```

With the code in the second snippet in your question, your `try`/`catch` *block* will never do anything useful, because any problem will trigger the `.catch` method, and because the Promise isn't being `await`ed. Better not to mix the two styles - either pick `await` and `try`/`catch`or `.then` and `.catch`, but not both, else the control flow may become difficult to make sense of.

Comment: Either `userResult` or `result`. Also your second example doesn't need to nest the chain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, async-await can be used in functions which returns a promise.
Why we have to use `await` instead of `then`. `await` process the code asynchronously by  making the execution feel like synchronous.

In your first example, everything works fine as expected. But in the second one, you need to await the findOne query. Here the fineOne will work asynchronously

```
exports.query = async(req, res) => {
   try{
      user.findOne({})
         .then(async(result) =>{
              let orderResult = await order.findOne({id: result.id})
         .catch(e => res.send(e)
   } catch(error) {
      res.send(error)
   }
}
```

which can be again simplified to

```
exports.query = async(req, res) => {
   try{
      let result = await user.findOne({});
      let orderResult  = order.findOne({id: result.id});

   } catch(error) {
      res.send(error)
   }
}
```